# MongoDb relations not connected with other

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

I am writing a cook book in node.js. Im new to this language and mongoDB concept. I identify that I need to have a user who has favorite recipes nad in favorite recipes I am going to store recipes

My model look like that and something its wrong here

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  userId: {type: String, required: true},
  favorites: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Favorites',
  }],
});

favoritesSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
  recipes: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Recipes',
  }],
  startOfRecipe: {type: Date},

});

recipeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, unique: true},
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Favorites = mongoose.model('Favorites', favoritesSchema);
const Recipes = mongoose.model('Recipes', recipeSchema);
module.exports = {User, Favorites, Recipes};
```

I wrote a function which looking for user and then store favorite recipe

```
  addFav(fav, userId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      schema.User.findOne({userId: userId}, function(err, user) {
        if (err || !user) {

        } else {
          schema.Favorites.create({
            name: fav,
          }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            resolve('noResult');
          });

          resolve(user);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

and it saves but if I call my user the array favorites is always empty

```
{ favorites: [],
  _id: 5cb32867d2dfea0cadd79ecb,
  name: 'Anna',
  userId:
   'AF322',
  __v: 0 }
```

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I created subschema of `favorites` & `recipes`, get user details using `userId` and push `favorites` object into `favorites` field

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  userId: {type: String, required: true},
  favorites: [favoritesSchema],
});

favoritesSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
  recipes: [recipeSchema],
  startOfRecipe: {type: Date},

});

recipeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, unique: true},
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

addFav(fav, userId) {
    return Schema.User.update({_id:userId}, {$set:{$push:{favorites:fav}}})
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work :( As result I am getting { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }. Shouldn't I use method create to treate a new favorite